# MySQL syntax error; don't know where to begin

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a table. I think the specifications of the table should be pretty obvious from the command I'm running:

```
create table users{
    id mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment,
    username varchar(40) not null,
    sprinkles bigint unsigned not null,
    passhash binary(64) not null,
    passsalt binary(64) not null,
    x decimal(10,1),
    y decimal(10,1),
    primary key (id),
    unique key idx_unique_username (username)
} engine = INNODB DEFAULT character set = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

However, when I try entering that into MySQL, it gives me this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{
id mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment,
username varchar(40) not null,
' at line 1
```

My mysql version is `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Begin with your parentheses shape.

Hint: find *any* `create table` example and compare to what you have

Hint 2: when mysql returns you a error about incorrect syntax - it points directly to the first token it couldn't parse. So your attention should be drawn to that exact character and some characters before it.

Comment: Oh God this is the most embarrassingly stupid question I've ever asked.

Comment: Re: Hint 2, when I edited the innards to try to figure it out, it actually cut off at seemingly random places. The token it ends on is "sprinkles", and it was moving around when I added things to the end of "username", for example. What was confusing me is that I wasn't at all focused on the beginning or end. Anyways, thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Switch out the { } brackets you have encapsulating your table information, replace them with ( ) parentheses, and you should be good to go.